# More than one post build scripts in buildroot

Tags: arm, embedded-linux, buildroot

I am pretty new to buildroot and I wish to add more than 1 post-build scripts, as the documentation says:

> 3.3.1. Customizing the generated target filesystem
>
> > In the Buildroot configuration, you can specify the paths to one or more post-build scripts. These scripts are called in the given order, after Buildroot builds all the selected software, but before the rootfs images are assembled. The BR2_ROOTFS_POST_BUILD_SCRIPT allows you to specify the location of your post-build scripts

http://buildroot.uclibc.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#rootfs-custom

How can I specify more than one value in a buildroot setting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See: [buildroot Makefile](http://git.buildroot.net/buildroot/tree/Makefile), especially lines 782-784.

The string is passed to a shell's `for` loop. So a space separator should be used.  Each script gets a `TARGET_DIR` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, I am running Armadeus 5.2 which only includes Buildroot 2012.02, which does not allow more than 1 post build script. Buildroot 2013.02 does.

Comment: It should be easy to copy the portion of the `Makefile` to support it.

Answer (score 0):

Current docs have made it clearer now:

> To enable this feature, specify a space-separated list of post-build scripts in config option BR2_ROOTFS_POST_BUILD_SCRIPT

So space separated as Artless deduced from the source.